# Android Kotlin - Storing of Gson casted API data into a Room Database

Tags: android, kotlin, gson, android-room

I am using `okhttp` to fetch Json data from an API, casting it into Gson for some other purposes, and at the same time, storing of the API data into a `Room Database`. *(It can be storing of the API json data itself, or the casted Gson version)* However, I am unsuccessful in this, and hope you could point me to the direction where I am going wrong.

I think i'm missing a `typeConverter` to convert the data retrieved from API and casted into `GSON`, to be stored in the `Room database`. But i'm not sure if i'm correct in this, or if my approach is correct in the first place.

Or could it be an issue with the fact that I have an `Entities data class`, but `gsonData` is casted into `SampleData data class`?

**DataGetter**

```
...
...
...
// this suspend function is run within a coroutine.
private suspend fun APICall(url: String, pageNumber: Int, context: Context){
    val urlRequest = Request.Builder().url(url).build()  // Building of the URL to fetch data
    httpClient.newCall(urlRequest).enqueue(object : Callback {
        // onFailure -> cutting this out to shorten code
        // onResponse is where I am fetching the data and calling put to DB
        override fun onResponse(call: Call, response: Response) {
            val dataString = response.body!!.string()
            val gsonData = gsonResult.fromJson(dataString, SampleData::class.java)
            // Do some other stuffs with gsonData separately. This doesn't return anything to gsonData. 
            putToRoomDb(gsonData, context)  // This will eventually be done via another coroutine.
        }
    }
}

private suspend fun putToRoomDb(sampleData: SampleData, context: Context) {        
    val db = MyOnlyDatabase.getInstance(context)
    db.MyOnlyDao().updateOrInsert(sampleData)
}
```

**Entity**

```
@Entity(tableName = "sample_data_code_names")
data class SampleDataEntities(
    @PrimaryKey
    var Code: Int,
    val Name: String,
    val Description: String,
    val Item1: String,
    val Item2: String
)
```

**Dao**

```
@Dao
interface SampleDataDao {
    @Insert(onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.REPLACE)
    suspend fun updateOrInsert(sampleDataEntities: SampleDataEntities)
}
```

**Database**

```
@Database(entities = [SampleDataEntities::class], version = 1, exportSchema = false)
abstract class MyOnlyDatabase: RoomDatabase() {
    abstract fun sampleDataDao(): SampleDataDao 

    companion object {  
        @Volatile
        private var instance: MyOnlyDatabase? = null    
        fun getInstance(context: Context): MyOnlyDatabase{
            return instance ?: synchronized(this) {                   
                instance ?: buildDatabase(context).also { instance = it }
            }
        }

        private fun buildDatabase(context: Context): MyOnlyDatabase{
            return Room.databaseBuilder(context, MyOnlyDatabase::class.java, "MyOnlyDatabase.db")
                .fallbackToDestructiveMigration()                   
                .build()                                                     
        }
    }
}
```

**Note**: Below is the `data class` for which `gsonData` is casted into.

```
data class SampleData(val value: List<SampleDataInfoItems>)
data class SampleDataInfoItems(
    val Code: String,
    val Name: String,
    val Description: String,
    val Item1: BigDecimal,
    val Item2: BigDecimal
)
```

Answer (score 0):

You are not annotating your fields according to the `JSON` response that is coming from the server.

```
data class SampleDataInfoItems(
    @SerializedName("name_this_field_on_json")
    val Code: String,
    @SerializedName("and_so_on_for_all_fields")
    val Name: String,
    val Description: String,
    val Item1: BigDecimal,
    val Item2: BigDecimal
)
```

Also I think you need the [GsonConververFactory](https://github.com/square/retrofit/tree/master/retrofit-converters/gson) for Retrofit.

Comment: Are you trying to say that `@Entity(tableName = "sample_data_code_names")` should be on my `SampleDataInfoItems` data class? But the `gsonData` that gets passed is from `data class SampleData` and not `data class SampleDataInfoItems`

Comment: You either use different models and extract them or you can use the same model for both db and gson

Comment: Hmm, I suppose it makes sense to use the same model for both db and gson. However, what I don't understand is that, `gsonData` is of type `SampleData`. Which contains `SampleDataInfoItems`. Wouldn't it be a mismatched type?